# Bad practice to willfully allow errors using updateData?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I only want to update a document if it exists and I don't want to use a transaction because it's not offline-capable. Therefore, I use `updateData()`. However, this task is common in the UX and is likely to fail (the document won't exist) half of the time. I shudder at the idea of allowing errors that I know will happen but I see no other way to preserve offline capability and update documents only when they exist. Is this frowned upon by Firestore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore doesn't really care if your update fails when a document doesn't exist.